# Delete border of mat-form-field with input (also for hover and focus)

Tags: html, css, input, angular8, mat-form-field

I'm having a hard time styling my `mat-form-field`.
What I want is to delete the border from the field, also when the field is focused and the user is on hover. Right now I have this:

[image]

and I need to delete that border outside of my input. This is my form field:

```
<mat-form-field class="search-field" appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" >
  <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

and in .scss:

```
mat-form-field.search-field {
    .mat-form-field-flex {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 2rem;
        color: transparent;

        .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-focused .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
            border-style: none;
        }

    }
}
```

The "first" style is correctly applied, but not the style for the border.
Also I'm not totally sure this is the best way to stile it, but in the docs there is no indication on how to change all these parts.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the Material styles are enforced with the `!important` flag. You can either try to overwrite them using `!important` in your code, which I wouldn't recommend, since it may not even work. You could try using `::ng-deep`, tho. Material elements are not really str8 forward for modification, so either way, you'll have to 'hack' into it. Good luck :)